# How to compare datetime field from Doctrine2 with a date?

Tags: datetime, symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to get the items which were created today with by a QueryBuilder from Doctrine2. I want to compare the createdAt(Datetime) field with today parameter(Date). Is it possible to do that in one query?

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('i');
$qb->innerJoin('i.type', 'it');
$qb->andWhere('it.name = :type');
$qb->andWhere('i.createdAt < :today');
// i.createdAt == datetime and :today parameter is a date
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

one idea is to extract from the date: the year, month and day. And then

```
$qb->select('p')
   ->where('YEAR(p.postDate) = :year')
   ->andWhere('MONTH(p.postDate) = :month')
   ->andWhere('DAY(p.postDate) = :day');

$qb->setParameter('year', $year)
   ->setParameter('month', $month)
   ->setParameter('day', $day);
```

MONTH DAY, and YEAR you take out the DoctrineExtensions from

e.g.

[DoctrineExtensions](https://github.com/simukti/DoctrineExtensions)

This works for me. You only need the files: day.php, month.php and year.php.....

You get the month e.g.:

```
    $datetime = new \DateTime("now");
    $month = $datetime->format('m');
    echo $month;
```

Copy day.php, month.php and year.php to your bundle Xy\TestBundle\Dql
Register the new functions in app\config.yml with

```
doctrine:


orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
    entity_managers:
        default:
            auto_mapping: true
            dql:
                datetime_functions:
                    month: Xy\TestBundle\Dql\Month
                    year: Xy\TestBundle\Dql\Year
                    day: Xy\TestBundle\Dql\Day
```

Comment: It working, but it's little bit dirty. Do you know if DATE() function for QueryBuilder is provided with this bundle?

Comment: @jooyce there isn't. [Here](https://github.com/simukti/DoctrineExtensions/tree/master/lib/DoctrineExtensions/Query/Mysql) is the list of extensions available

Comment: @gperriard not dirty at all. Just elementary.

Answer (score 17):

There is better option than adding the doctrine extension for date.

First you need to get start-datetime and end-datetime :

```
$today_startdatetime = \DateTime::createFromFormat( "Y-m-d H:i:s", date("Y-m-d 00:00:00") );
$today_enddatetime = \DateTime::createFromFormat( "Y-m-d H:i:s", date("Y-m-d 23:59:59") );
```

Now use them in query :

```
$em = \Zend_Registry::get('em');
$qb_1 = $em->createQueryBuilder();
$q_1 = $qb_1->select('wsh')
    ->from('\Entities\wishes', 'wsh')
    ->where('wsh.created_at >= :today_startdatetime')
    ->andWhere('wsh.created_at <= :today_enddatetime');


$q_1->setParameter('today_startdatetime', $today_startdatetime);
$q_1->setParameter('today_enddatetime', $today_enddatetime);
$result= $q_1->getQuery ()->getResult ();
```

Comment: best answer here around!

Comment: this is a more straight forward answer. SAD that ORM doesn't provide specific function for this

Answer (score 15):

It is also possible to use built-in function `DATE_DIFF(date1, date2)` which returns difference in days. Check [docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html?highlight=setparameter#dql-functions)

```
$result = $this->createQueryBuilder('l')
    ->where('DATE_DIFF(l.startDate, CURRENT_DATE()) = 0')
```

Answer (score 13):

It's rare that such a mature ORM does not provide the `DATE`  function. However, to get a date out of a datetime field, you can apply the `SUBSTRING` function like this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(i.dateTimeField,1,10) FROM tableName i
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Tks for you answered!Helps a lot!

Comment: Kind of hacky fix, until DATE function is supported by Doctrine! thanks,,

Answer (score 5):

You have to add to your query QueryBuilder the `today` parameter.

```
$today = new \DateTime();
$qb->setParameter('today', $today->format('Y-m-d'));
```

With the QueryBuilder, you can compare dates to DateTime with the format `'Y-m-d'`

Comment: I tried to manage with $today->format('Y-m-d') as parameter but I've got no result. I need to get only 'Y-m-d' for 'createdAt' field.

Comment: Have you tried to directly pass a `DateTime` object as a parameter ?

Comment: Yes, but that's not the same value (when I compare them I've got false) and It's not exactly what I would. I would to get items that were created on the same day, but at any time.

i.createdAt = 2012-05-21 13:18:27
$today = 2012-05-21 14:23:34

Answer (score 3):

An easy solution would be to format the datetime accordingly

```
public function getWithStartingPremium(\DateTime $datetime)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c');

    return $qb
        ->innerJoin('c.collegePremium', 'cp')
        ->where($qb->expr()->eq('cp.start', ':date'))
        ->setParameters(array(
            'date' => $datetime->format('Y-m-d'),
        ))
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to add an external extension just for this, you can search your datetime as a string.

```
$today = new \DateTime();

$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('i');
$qb->innerJoin('i.type', 'it');
$qb->andWhere('it.name = :type');
$qb->andWhere('i.createdAt LIKE :today');
$qb->setParameter('today', $today->format('Y-m-d').'%');
```

PS: I know this is an old question, but I had this problem and used this solution.