# Compare two date fields in doctrine (ignoring the time part)

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am trying to compare if two fields have same date. They may have different time part, but if the date is the same I count them as equal.

```
$q = $this->createQueryBuilder("a")
->select('c.year,c.number')
->leftJoin('a.conflict', 'c')
->where("a.awardIssuedDate = c.awardDeadlineInit")
->getQuery();
$cases =  $q->getResult();
return $cases;
```

The fields `awardIssuedDate` and `awardDeadlineInit` are datetime fields. I want to compare and check if they have the same date (not necessarily the same time) but can't make it.

Comment: Where's your `->from('YourBundle:YourEntity', 'c')` after select ?

Comment: `->where("DATEDIFF(a.awardIssuedDate, c.awardDeadlineInit) = 0")`

Comment: @mudasobwa's suggestion is seems legit. But I believe you will find kind a same question in here :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10681158/how-to-compare-datetime-field-from-doctrine2-with-a-date

Comment: @AnjanaSilva I don't need to call from method as this code is in my entity repository.

Comment: @mudasobwa it got error with undefined DATEDIFF

Comment: if that is codeigniter...try this...left join command: 

$this->db->join('comments', 'comments.id = blogs.id', 'left');

see the word "left" on the 3rd arguments.

Comment: It is Symfony2 framework

Comment: try to put your $q in die($q) after ->getQuery(); to see the output of your query then try to manually try it in your database application. that the way i troubleshoot my program. I just want to share.

Comment: SELECT c.year,c.number FROM ACF\CaseBundle\Entity\ConflictOutcome a LEFT JOIN a.conflict c WHERE DATEDIFF(a.awardIssuedDate, c.awardDeadlineInit) = 0

Comment: I got the solution. We should not use DATEDIFF but DATE_DIFF